# Sort answers by "Votes over Time Average" or by "Votes over per 100 reviews"

Tags: feature-request, answers, sorting

Currently we have 3 ways of sorting answers: active, oldest, votes. Can we have a fourth sorting way of "Votes over time average"? Currently if we sort answers by "votes", an 4 year-old answer which got 4 votes will be on top of a 2 year-old answer which got 3 votes. However by a "Votes over time average" sorting, an 4 year-old answer which got 4 votes will be under a 2 year-old answer which got 3 votes. because the latter one got more votes per time unit average(4/4=1 vote per year VS 3/2=1.5 votes per year), so it is more likely a better answer. Otherwise, as we see, the oldest answers almost got privilege of sorting on top, and new good answers get few chance of advancing to top because they are way too low to get reviewed.

Depends on how long the question was posted, the time average can be per day, per month, or per year.

"Votes over per 100 reviews" can have similar effects as "Votes over Time Average" and can be more precise. But this will require the system counts how many reviews for each answer since it was posted.

This sorting does not replace the current sorting of "Votes". This is just a new option for people preferring to sort answers logically wise. So, it does not force others to do it.

Please vote to this feature request!

Comment: Sounds too confusing, people will misclick it and have no idea what's going on, posting bug reports on meta that the sort is broken.

Comment: That would be even more confusing, but I'm only  one person, maybe others will find it more intuitive.

Comment: What's your mathematical formula to combine freshness and votes? Do you think many people will agree with your choice of weights? I have downvoted your question because you failed to provide an algorithm and quantitative arguments for the change (e.g. SEDE query results).

Comment: Fine, what is **your way**? If there is no algorithm in the question, the question lacks substance.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to improve it with any requested clarifications instead of creating a comment trail.

Comment: The [better formula has already been developed](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/49787/), but shows no signs of being implemented.